# foreach loop with nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

My array $array contains the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array (
               [label] => Location and Contact
               [description] =>
      ) [1] => Array (
               [label] => Province
               [name] => province
               [options] => Array ( [0] => Province 1
                                    [1] => Province 2
                                    [2] => Province 3 )
      ) [2] => Array (
               [label] => City
               [name] => city
               [options] => Array ( [0] => City 1
                                    [1] => City 2
                                    [2] => City 3 )
      )
```

What I want to achieve is to loop those three cities at the bottom, probably with the use of the [name] => city.

What I've tried so far (which isn't really looking good):

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {

            foreach ($arr['options'] as $option) {
            ?>
            &raquo; <?php echo $option; ?><br />
             <?php
            }

}
```

My obvious problem with the code is the foreach loop within foreach loop plus I haven't figured out how to identify [name] => city from [name] => province, both of them having [options].

I'm fairly new to looping arrays.

**UPDATE (WITH MY ANSWER)**

Combining worldofjr's answer and my modification so I can enclose each loop in a container like `<li>, <option>, <div>`, etc, I just created two foreach's:

```
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        if($arr['name'] == "city") {
            $cities = $arr['options'];
        }
    }
    echo '<select>';
    foreach($cities as $city){

            echo '<option value="'.$city.'" class="class1 class2" data-att="att">'.$city.'</option>';

    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: If you want to display only cities or provinces then use `array_filter`

Comment: You have not made it very clean what you want the end result to be.  If you clarify your question you will get some better answers.

Comment: @mschuett To requote the end result I wanted: "What I want to achieve is to loop those three cities at the bottom, probably with the use of the [name] => city."

Comment: To display each city in a list, you don't need the 2nd `foreach`. Just wrap the `implode()` with list tags, ie; `echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $arr['options']) . "</li></ul>";`

Comment: @worldofjr I can do that, but for complicated containers like `<option>` with values and classes, it's kinda confusing for me if I will use implodes.

Comment: Fair enough. It does depend on your particular situation, but if you do have a problem (and can't find an answer on SO) do ask another question.

Comment: What I mean is something like this:`echo '<option value="'.$city.'" class="class1 class2 class3" data-something="'.$city.'">" . implode('</option><option value="'.$city.'" class="class1 class2 class3" data-something="'.$city.'">', $arr['options']) . "</option>';`. That would be too much for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `implode($glue,$array)` as follows;

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if($arr['name'] == "city") {
        echo implode('<br>',$arr['options']);
    }
}
```

or if you want to print a list of the cities, wrap the `implode()` with list tags, like this;

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if($arr['name'] == "city") {
        echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $arr['options']) . "</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

See [PHP manual: implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Helped a lot. Need to study more about implodes and explodes. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand at all, but I what you want is simply output the three cities, yo can do this

```
foreach ($array as $arr) 
{
    if ($arry['name'] == 'city') 
    {
        foreach ($arr['options'] as $option) 
        {
            echo $option . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

That's enough?